# How do I change the input language programmatically with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So here is my objective. I want to make a button on an excel spreadsheet that changes the input language to Japanese. I saw this thread

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/173705-change-system-keyboard-language-with-vba/

He called activatekeyboardlayout, but it doesn't appear to do anything. the function calls activekeyboardlayout, and nothing changes. typing still gives american letters. I have looked at this for a couple hours and i dont feel like i have a firm grasp of it, so im asking for help.

im using excel 2013, with windows 10

Comment: Do you have a 64bit system or a 32bit system? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449207/how-can-i-call-activatekeyboardlayout-from-64bit-windows-vista-using-vba

Comment: This Works fine for me ...  you need to have the lang you try using installed in your compyter. and added to code `Private Const jap = 1041` under `Private Const eng = 1033` and change `Call ActivateKeyboardLayout(MKD, 0)
`  to `Call ActivateKeyboardLayout(jap, 0)` or just past the code you used so we can help you